# Is there a spec-compliant practice for an image with no relevant alt text?

Tags: html, attributes, w3c-validation, alt, wcag

I'm implementing Jssor's Bootstrap Carousel Slider on a web page. Using W3C's validation tool I'm getting an error for the lack of alt text for this particular image:

```
<div data-u="loading" class="jssorl-009-spin" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
    <img style="margin-top:-19px;position:relative;top:50%;width:38px;height:38px;" src="/svg/loading/static-svg/spin.svg" />
</div>
```

The image is just a spinning disk used to represent the Jssor slider loading. I'm curious as to whether I should be using alt text on this image or not. So far my research points to just including a blank `alt=""` attribute; is there an authoritative reference for whether this should be included and left blank, or if it should be avoided if I don't have any alt text?

Comment: you could make it into a background image, otherwise just describe what it is - `alt="a loading spinner"`.  The alt text is what appears if the image doesn't so I would say, if your going to use an image on the page and not as a background image, then you should describe it to users who don't have browser that can see it and display the text instead

Comment: This is a good article about using alt text: https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/

Comment: @Pete thanks for the article, yeah think I'm just going to go with "a loading spinner" rather than having no alt attribute.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the W3C's Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI) recommendations, an empty `alt=""` attribute should be used so it can be ignored by the screen readers.

> Decorative images don’t add information to the content of a page. For example, the information provided by the image might already be given using adjacent text, or the image might be included to make the website more visually attractive.
>
> In these cases, a null (empty) `alt` text should be provided (`alt=""`) so that they can be ignored by assistive technologies, such as screen readers. Text values for these types of images would add audible clutter to screen reader output or could distract users if the topic is different from that in adjacent text. Leaving out the alt attribute is also not an option because when it is not provided, some screen readers will announce the file name of the image instead.

Source: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decorative/

Comment: A loading spinner isn't merely decorative. It serves the function of indicating that something is going to load. If it's there for much longer than expected the page visitor interprets that something isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I generally don't like the idea of an empty `alt` attribute when I could put something meaningful.  In particular when a form that might take a while is submitted, I show the spinner to indicate that the user has pressed the right button and something is going to happen - but for now they should wait while it is processing.

So my plan is to make alt="Processing..." and making that a translatable string in my application.

Any comments would be welcome.